# Can't access WCF service through browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been following this series of tutorials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx) on getting started with WCF, and it's all been going well up until step 3 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically up until the bottom, where it says "Open Internet Explorer and browse to the service's debug page at http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService"

Basically, what this should be doing (I assume, I've never tried this before today) is opening some sort of web interface to this service, where I can edit it.

I've tried using both Chrome and IE, and neither of them can connect. I've tried lots of different IP addresses (localhost, 192.168.1.8, etc.) and they all give back the generic "This webpage is not available".

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Preview (that MIGHT be the problem, but it shouldn't be...) run as administrator (I've tried running the .exe directly as well) on Windows 8.1, coding in C#. I'm not too experienced in networking things, so I might be missing something obvious... any ideas?

Comment: Alright, so I managed to get up to the last step, where you make a client for this server. I then get a 404 error in the program (using the URL I'm supposed to use), and trying the wcftestclient with http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService gives me an HTTP 400 again. Using the old IP that worked earlier doesn't work (it's not run in VS now), and it says "because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8733" Odd....

Comment: Wait, I figured it out. Turns out I forgot (I don't think it ever told me to...) to change, in the original service contract app.config, the address that it tries to go to. So, the problem is, basically, they weren't trying to get to the same address, so there was SOMETHING there, just not the actual service... yaaayy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the main library (the one with the contract and  implementation), in App.config, I forgot to change the address that it binds to. Setting this to the desired one (http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService) seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 400 is significant. It means bad request - eg your service isn't receiving input in a way it expected, but it is there. Please update your question. That sounds like a mistake in your WCF config. Try this... Open up a command prompt and run C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat (Path for 2013, update as req'd). Then enter the command wcftestclient. It'll open up a gui that you can connect to the same url you're browsing to. It will attempt to talk to any WCF service listening there.

Comment: Alright, I'll try all those and see what I come up with (I am running VS as admin at this point, by the way), and I've already got a generic catch statement in the program.

Comment: Alright, so, I disabled my firewall, checked (there isn't anything running on port 8000, and when I run the server, it does show up there), I ran as administrator, and I am catching literally all exceptions. It still does not connect, however.

Comment: Oh, hey, I noticed something interesting. When I run the service, there's an icon in the notification bar. When I clicked on it and hit "open", I see something about this address: "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrarySandbox/Service1/mex"... that seems odd. This only shows up when I run from visual studio: running the exe by itself does not produce this notification icon. Accessing THAT port (8733) instead of 8000 then produces a "Service not Found 503" error.

Comment: Also, accessing the original link makes an Http 400 error, just in case anyone cares.

Comment: HTTP 400 is significant. It means bad request - eg your service isn't receiving input in a way it expected, but it _is_ there. In future, a little clarification on the exact error would help. That sounds like a mistake in your WCF config. Try this... Open up a command prompt and run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` (Path for 2013, update as req'd). Then enter the command `wcftestclient`. It'll open up a gui that you can connect to the same url you're browsing to. It will attempt to talk to any WCF service listening there.